# Where clause in "sub models" in CakePhp 2.0

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

How can I insert a where clause about Model 'Why' in this code.

I have to filter by a specific `class_id` of table Whies (in Cake is model 'Why').

You should know that Pilot hasMany Why.

Thanks for help

```
$allplants = $this->Plant->find('all',[
    'contain'=>array('Pilot'=>array(
    'Lever',
    'Area',
    'Why',
    'conditions'=> array('published' => 1, $conditions,"OR"=>$or_conditions))),
    'conditions' => $plantConditions]
);
```

Comment: Do you want to filter Plants based on conditions of Why ?

Comment: What do you want to ask?

Comment: @Ved Kind of,I need to get data of Plants,Pilots and Whies where the field class_id of table Whies is a specific one(which I'll set by myself)

Answer (score 0):

Try Once, similar code that i implemented works in cakephp3.

```
$allplants= $this->Plant->find('all')->contain(['Pilot', 'Lever', 'Area'])
            ->innerJoinWith('Pilot.Why', function ($q) {
                return $q->where($WhyConditions);
            })
            ->conditions($plantConditions);
```

Comment: Error: Call to a member function contain() on array

Comment: may be my code is not compatible cake php2, read this, if it can help https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables